# Android Studio doesn't see all API platforms

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Today I decided to move from the manual Android SDK Tools and IntelliJ IDEA to AndroidStudio. So I uninstalled everything (on a Mac OS X Yosemite) and install AndroidStudio.

By default, AndroidStudio installs API platform 21. I want my project to work with API platform 19, so I opened the SDK Manager from the Tools menu and installed the API 19 SDK and images.

However, when I open the Project Structure window to select an android SDK, the Module SDK combo box only shows API platform 21. I've closed and reopened Android Studio, and still - just one API platform is listed.

What can be the problem?

UPDATE:
Manually selecting the API 19 folder and adding it as a new SDK did not work. However, deleting the API 21 SDK did work - after that the API 19 SDK appeared. I reinstalled API 21, but sure enough - only API 19 appears.

Comment: Looking at your **sdk** location (Project structure -> SDK location), do you have API 19 files under that location? (../sdk/platforms/android-19/)

Comment: Yep, right next to android-21 .

Comment: I kinda miss IntelliJ.

Comment: That is wierd, please be sure that you are running the latest Android Studio (1.0.2) with the latest build tools. Double check if your **sdk** folder matches the one set in Project Structure -> SDK location, and that you indeed have all the sdk's stored there (and that you are downloading your sdk's from SDK Manager inside Studio - where you can see the path the sdk's are stored) If that is all set, try reinstalling Android Studio, and if that doesn't work, it might be a bug. Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, so you shouldn't have no problems adapting, since it is *almost* the same ;)

Comment: 1.0.2? I downloaded it Thursday, and received 1.0.1 from the Android Studio Download page. Updated to 1.0.2. Problem still persists. This was originally an IntelliJ IDEA 13 project, perhaps that's what causes this.